# Reporting service error while accessing reports by users

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am getting below error while someone(user) trying to access my SSRS reports that are deployed on report server.
Also I have added the specified user into security group using site setting.

How could I give the permission to a users/group of users.

```
Reporting Services Error   
________________________________


*   An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted) 

    *   The execution failed for the shared data set 'DataSetReportData'. (rsDataSetExecutionError) 

        *   Cannot create a connection to data source ' Data source for shared dataset'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection) 

            *   For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors
```

Could someone help on this ?

Thanks

Comment: have you add the user as a login to in SQL server and granted him/her access to the database you are connecting too?

Comment: Also, How have you configured the data source for the report server? The Data Source tab is available if you click on the report server node (from the AdminUI) and bring up its properties window. What settings are configured for the data source currently?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error msg. In my case, the issue was with hosts file in the SSRS server (c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc). The hosts file had the data source server IP address hard coded in there. Commenting out the line resolved the issue. Mapping contained in the hosts file was overriding information that would be retrieved from DNS server.